# enable temporary file creation and usage in Apache/PHP by Python/R/any external program - best options

Tags: php, python, apache, r

I have a python/R script, that uses both Python and R to compute a figure. The actual figure is generated by R and it can be stored as a PNG image. This works fine when tested on the machine, in a folder with correct permissions, but I have to do it online now. I have an Apache/PHP interface that sends the user data to the Python script, and the Python script works with R to compute the figure.

At this moment the picture cannot be stored on Apache by R. What is the best way to enable this temporary file creation by external programs like R and Python? Further on, I need the picture to be displayed, then deleted at the end of the PHP session.

While certainly useful, any methods that only allow access for Python, or R are not good enough. My question is one of client-server 'modus operandi' in Apache: suppose program X is called by PHP. How is it best to allow program X to store and send pictures/text/whatever to PHP and how to implement that?

Creating a server-accessible folder with full permissions seems like a security black hole.

Comment: With Python you could look at using mod_wsgi to connect it directly to Apache, but I don't know of anything equivalent for R.

Comment: Surely you don't need "full permissions".  644 should be good enough, i.e. only the owner can write, everyone else can read, no-one can execute.

Answer (score 1):

With R, you can `tempfile` generates filenames for temp files.  You could also use `file.remove` to delete the file later, but it sounds like this would be done best from PHP code (if it to be removed when the PHP session finishes).

```
plot_file <- paste(tempfile(tmpdir = "some_dir_with_write_permission"), "png", sep = ".")

png(plot_file)
plot(1:10)
dev.off()

#later on ...
file.remove(plot_file)
```

Comment: The Apache server does not allow the writing of files by R on it's directories. How can I enable that?

Comment: Depends upon your OS.  In the folder that you want to write to, you'll need to change the write permissions.

Comment: Relaxing write permission on a server-accessible folder creates a security hole. There must be a better option. Anyway, I will temporarily verify your tempfile tip.

Comment: With `ASP.NET` you have a special folder, `App_Data`, for storing files like this. I presume that there's an `Apache` equivalent but you'll have to ask an `Apache` expert to find out what it is.